# How to check a string is numeric using Regex in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, isnumeric

IsNumeric allows below special characters

```
`SELECT  ISNUMERIC('10.50') as '10.50'
 ISNUMERIC('10,50') as '10,50'
 ,ISNUMERIC('-') as '-'
 ,ISNUMERIC('+') as '+'
 ,ISNUMERIC('$') as '$'
 ,ISNUMERIC('.') as '.'
 ,ISNUMERIC(',') as ','
 ,ISNUMERIC('\') as '\'`
```

So, I wanted to use RegEx https:// regexr.com/4gjhm to validate my numeric which must allow numbers and dot only.

Tried Regex ^[0-9]+[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$ with the help of `PATINDEX`, but didn't get the expected results

```
 `DECLARE @Amount As NVARCHAR(50) = '150';
  SELECT CASE 
            WHEN @Amount LIKE '%^[0-9]+[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$%'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS IsNumericResult`
```

Valid Ex: 10, 10.01, .20
Invalid Ex: 10.50.20, 10..20, etc

Is this possible to achieve through `LIKE` or `PATINDEX` in SQL Server 2017?

Comment: `%^ ...$%` seems a bit contradictory to me.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC()` won't help there as you already state, instead you can use `TRY_CAST() / TRY_CONVERT()`. Without the needs to Regex.

Comment: how about remove . and digits and then see inf there's anything left in the string...

Comment: What is the end goal here? Why are you validating that the string is of that pattern? Is it to detect if it will cast to `numeric` without error or some other reason?

Comment: The problem is, SQL Server does not support regular expressions. Whereas you can match single characters with a range `[0-9]` or set `[01234]` you can't use `+` or `*` to match an instictinct count of them. Ie something like `[0-9]+` will match `1+` but not `123`. So you might be best off with @Sami answer and add some additional tests to exclude for instance `+123` or `-1.5`

Comment: SQL Server does not offer out-of-the-box regular expression support, but regardless, the regular expression in the question is not good enough - since it will deem strings like `4.23E-8` as not numbers - which is clearly wrong.

Comment: The question no one has asked yet - Why are you using `nvarchar(50)` to store numbers in the first place? Use an appropriate data type and all your problems will go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`TRY_CAST()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** or **[`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** without the need to Regex expression

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(@Amount AS INT) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END IsNumericResult
```

You can change `INT` there to numeric or decimal as needed.

eg:

```
SELECT V Value,
       CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(V AS DECIMAL(10,2)) IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END IsNumericResult
FROM
(VALUES ('10.50'), ('+'), ('$'), ('-'), ('11')) T(V);
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e418321711e9d6fe98e11b8c2cfe689a) to see how it's working.

Comment: This will also allow `+10.5` and `-11` which is not valid according to the op original question.

Comment: Try ` ('+0'), ('$0'), ('-0') ` the only difference with `ISNUMERIC` is `('$0')`

Comment: @derpirscher 1st the OP doesn't state that in his Q, 2nd `-11` isn't a number??? From where did that comes to your mind? There is no negative/positive numbers?

Comment: For the specific example strings they gave this has the desired effect. https://rextester.com/VJX9909

Comment: @Sami citing from the op question: "validate my numeric which must allow numbers and dot only" Yes `-11` is a number, but OP does not want to allow it, at least as I understand his question (and his inital regex which does not contain a negative sign)